# Doctrine join Entity with join OneToMany

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine, nested

I have entity named Sections, who have:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="sections")
 */
protected $products;
```

And entity named Product, who have:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Price", mappedBy="product")
 */
protected $price;
```

Now I use:

```
    $sectionsarray = $this->getDoctrine()
           ->getRepository('AsortBundle:Sections')
           ->createQueryBuilder('e')
           ->leftJoin('e.products', 'p')
           ->leftJoin('e.colors', 'c')
           ->select('e, p, c')
           ->orderBy('e.sequence', 'asc')
           ->addOrderBy('p.kolejnosc', 'asc')
           ->addOrderBy('c.sequence', 'asc')
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

How I can join price of these product? Price is array collection because it have four currencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I wrote custom getters and for now work nice :)

in Price Entity:

```
/**
 * Get val
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getValWithCurrency()
{
    return array($this->currency->getIso() => $this->val);
}
```

in Product Entity:

```
/**
 * Get val
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPriceArray()
{
    $arr = array();
    $pra = $this->price->toArray();
    foreach($pra as $k => $v){
        $a = $v->getValWithCurrency();
        $arr = array_merge($arr, $a);
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD6CX.png)

I can now add getter with currency from session or use currency session like a key.

And for get all:

```
    $c = $this->get('session')->get('currency');
    $sectionsarray = $this->getDoctrine()
           ->getRepository('AsortBundle:Sections')
           ->createQueryBuilder('e')
           ->select('e, p, c, prices, cur')
           ->leftJoin('e.products', 'p')
           ->leftJoin('p.price', 'prices')
           ->leftJoin('e.colors', 'c')
           ->leftJoin('prices.currency', 'cur')
           ->where('cur.iso = :sesscurr')
           ->setParameter('sesscurr', 'PLN')
           ->orderBy('e.sequence', 'asc')
           ->addOrderBy('p.kolejnosc', 'asc')
           ->addOrderBy('c.sequence', 'asc')
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Entity/Product.php

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Price", inversedBy="products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="price_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $price;
```

Entity/Price.php

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="price")
 */
private $products;
```

Repository/SectionsRpository.php

```
  $sectionsarray = $this->getDoctrine()
       ->getRepository('AsortBundle:Sections')
       ->createQueryBuilder('e')
       ->leftJoin('e.products', 'p')
       **->leftJoin('p.price', 'pr')**
       ->leftJoin('e.colors', 'c')
       ->select('e, p, c, pr')
       ->orderBy('e.sequence', 'asc')
       ->addOrderBy('p.kolejnosc', 'asc')
       ->addOrderBy('c.sequence', 'asc')
       ->getQuery()
       ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another join:

```
$sectionsarray = $this->getDoctrine()
           ->getRepository('AsortBundle:Sections')
           ->createQueryBuilder('e')
           ->select('e, p, c, prices')
           ->leftJoin('e.products', 'p')
           ->leftJoin('p.prices', 'prices')
           ->leftJoin('e.colors', 'c')
           ->orderBy('e.sequence', 'asc')
           ->addOrderBy('p.kolejnosc', 'asc')
           ->addOrderBy('c.sequence', 'asc')
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

I used prices instead of price, because field representing one to many should be in plural form.

Answer (score 0):

probably not quite what I meant

My Product Entity:

```
<?
namespace AsortBundle\Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Translatable\Translatable;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="asortyment")
 */
class Product implements Translatable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $img;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $rozmiar;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $dostepnosc = 1;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $kolejnosc;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint", length=13)
     */
    protected $kodog;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint", length=13)
     */
    protected $kodsz;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint", length=13, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $min;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $opt;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Price", mappedBy="product")
     */
    protected $price;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $description;

     /**
     * @Gedmo\Locale
     * Used locale to override Translation listener`s locale
     * this is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property
     */
    private $locale;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sections", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="section_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $sections;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sections", inversedBy="lazyproducts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="section_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    //protected $sections2;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Colors")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="color_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $color;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Magazyn")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="magazyn_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     **/
    private $magazyn;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->price = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }


    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setTranslatableLocale($locale)
    {
        $this->locale = $locale;
    }

    /**
     * Set img
     *
     * @param string $img
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setImg($img)
    {
        $this->img = $img;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get img
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getImg()
    {
        return $this->img;
    }

    /**
     * Set rozmiar
     *
     * @param string $rozmiar
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setRozmiar($rozmiar)
    {
        $this->rozmiar = $rozmiar;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get rozmiar
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getRozmiar()
    {
        return $this->rozmiar;
    }

    /**
     * Set dostepnosc
     *
     * @param integer $dostepnosc
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setDostepnosc($dostepnosc)
    {
        $this->dostepnosc = $dostepnosc;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dostepnosc
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getDostepnosc()
    {
        return $this->dostepnosc;
    }

    /**
     * Set kolejnosc
     *
     * @param integer $kolejnosc
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setKolejnosc($kolejnosc)
    {
        $this->kolejnosc = $kolejnosc;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get kolejnosc
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getKolejnosc()
    {
        return $this->kolejnosc;
    }

    /**
     * Set kodog
     *
     * @param integer $kodog
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setKodog($kodog)
    {
        $this->kodog = $kodog;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get kodog
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getKodog()
    {
        return $this->kodog;
    }

    /**
     * Set kodsz
     *
     * @param integer $kodsz
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setKodsz($kodsz)
    {
        $this->kodsz = $kodsz;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get kodsz
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getKodsz()
    {
        return $this->kodsz;
    }

    /**
     * Set parent
     *
     * @param integer $parent
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setParent($parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parent
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    /**
     * Set min
     *
     * @param integer $min
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setMin($min)
    {
        $this->min = $min;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get min
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getMin()
    {
        return $this->min;
    }

    /**
     * Set opt
     *
     * @param integer $opt
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setOpt($opt)
    {
        $this->opt = $opt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get opt
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getOpt()
    {
        return $this->opt;
    }

    /**
     * Set sections
     *
     * @param \AsortBundle\Entity\Sections $sections
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setSections(\AsortBundle\Entity\Sections $sections = null)
    {
        $this->sections = $sections;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get sections
     *
     * @return \AsortBundle\Entity\Sections 
     */
    public function getSections()
    {
        return $this->sections;
    }

    /**
     * Set magazyn
     *
     * @param \AsortBundle\Entity\Magazyn $magazyn
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setMagazyn(\AsortBundle\Entity\Magazyn $magazyn = null)
    {
        $this->magazyn = $magazyn;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get magazyn
     *
     * @return \AsortBundle\Entity\Magazyn 
     */
    public function getMagazyn()
    {
        return $this->magazyn;
    }


    /**
     * Set color
     *
     * @param \AsortBundle\Entity\Colors $color
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setColor(\AsortBundle\Entity\Colors $color = null)
    {
        $this->color = $color;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get color
     *
     * @return \AsortBundle\Entity\Colors 
     */
    public function getColor()
    {
        return $this->color;
    }

    /**
     * Add price
     *
     * @param \AsortBundle\Entity\Price $price
     * @return Product
     */
    public function addPrice(\AsortBundle\Entity\Price $price)
    {
        $this->price[] = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove price
     *
     * @param \AsortBundle\Entity\Price $price
     */
    public function removePrice(\AsortBundle\Entity\Price $price)
    {
        $this->price->removeElement($price);
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

}
```

My Price Entity:

```
<?
namespace AsortBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="price")
 */
class Price
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Currency")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="currency_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $currency;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="price")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", nullable=true, precision=10, scale=2)
     */
    protected $val; 

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set val
     *
     * @param string $val
     * @return Price
     */
    public function setVal($val)
    {
        $this->val = $val;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get val
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getVal()
    {
        return $this->val;
    }

    /**
     * Set currency
     *
     * @param \AsortBundle\Entity\Currency $currency
     * @return Price
     */
    public function setCurrency(\AsortBundle\Entity\Currency $currency = null)
    {
        $this->currency = $currency;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get currency
     *
     * @return \AsortBundle\Entity\Currency 
     */
    public function getCurrency()
    {
        return $this->currency;
    }

    /**
     * Set product
     *
     * @param \AsortBundle\Entity\Product $product
     * @return Price
     */
    public function setProduct(\AsortBundle\Entity\Product $product = null)
    {
        $this->product = $product;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get product
     *
     * @return \AsortBundle\Entity\Product 
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }
}
```

My Currency Entity:

```
<?
namespace AsortBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Translatable\Translatable;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="currency")
 */
class Currency implements Translatable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;  

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $iso;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Currency
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set iso
     *
     * @param string $iso
     * @return Currency
     */
    public function setIso($iso)
    {
        $this->iso = $iso;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get iso
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getIso()
    {
        return $this->iso;
    }

}
```

In session I got current cyrrency in ISO format like PLN, USD, EUR, RUB.

Now I want get from product his actually price in currency which I keep in session, like PLN.